# reCaptcha validating user when incorrect captcha submitted

Tags: php, codeigniter, recaptcha

I'm trying to setup reCaptcha for my Codeigniter project.  The recaptchalib.php file is saved in the views folder.

My registration view page includes the following:

```
<form method="post" action="cyoa/verify.php">
<?php
require_once('recaptchalib.php');
$publickey = "correct_public_key_inserted_here";
echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
?>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

My cyoa controller includes the following verify function:

```
public function verify()
{
    require_once('views/recaptchalib.php');
    $privatekey = "correct_private_key_inserted_here";
    $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

    if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
         "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
    } else {
        redirect('cyoa/index');
    // Your code here to handle a successful verification
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is that the page always redirects to cyoa/index.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is `!$resp->is_valid` returning false, or does it returns an error?
`if( $resp->is_valid === false)` may be better...

Comment: It seems to be working now.  It works with require_once('recaptchalib.php') in the controller and <form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>cyoa/verify"> in the view.  Thanks!